# Do Shi'ites believe that Hazrat Ali-Akbar, the son of Imam Hussein (a.s.), closely resembeled the Prophet (s)?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, shiism

It is said that Hazrat Ali Akbar (The oldest son of Imam Hussein (a.s.) was so similar in look and manner to Prophet Muhammad (pbuh). I wonder if there is any narration confirming this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم**

Hazrat Ali Akbar (a.s) was the most similar person to the Prophet (PBUH).
Zakir writes in his "*Tears and Tributes*" as such:

> It was a well-known fact amongst the Arabs throughout Hejaz that Ali
>   Akbar was bearing a remarkable resemblance to the Holy
>   Prophet(S.A.W.). In looks, in voice, in mannerism, in gait and in
>   every way, he resembled the Holy Prophet(S.A.W.). The resemblance was
>   so marked that people from far and wide were coming to see him, to be
>   reminded of the Holy Prophet(S.A.W.) whom they were missing so much.
>   Those who had not had the good fortune to see the Prophet were told by
>   their elders that Ali Akbar was the very image of Muhammad(S.A.W.) **(1)**.

When he asked for permission for going to the battlefield in the [day of Ashura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_Ashura), his father [Imam Hossein (a.s.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husayn_ibn_Ali) turned his face toward the sky and said:

> **> «اللهم اشهد على هؤلاء القوم فقد برز اليهم غلام اشبه الناس برسولك محمد خلقا و خلقا و منطقا و كنا اذا اشتقنا الى رؤية نبيك نظرنا
>   اليه...»**(2**
>
> “O Allah! Bear witness against these folks that a man who looks most
>   like Your Messenger Muhammad in his physique, manners, and eloquence
>   has come out to fight them! Whenever we missed seeing Your Prophet, we
>   would look at him.**

---

### References:

1-[Zakir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakir_Naik), Tears & Tributes, Shaheed Associates, India, 5th Revised Edition(1980).

2-[Biharol Anwar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bihar_al-Anwar), Allamah Mohammad Bagher Majlisi, Vol. 45, Page 43.